# WordPress - Stop plugins from requesting updates

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to actually stop plugins from querying their developers sites to find out if there is a new version.

From running New Relic on a client site I'm working on I can see that outside calls to developer sites (such as WPMUdev) take a hell of a long time to complete, and must be tying up CPU time that would be much better utilised by actual processes that are needed.

Needless to say, there is no reason for a live site to ever be updated directly, so I'm looking for a way to stop these queries happening. Updates can then be done on a local copy and pushed via GIT.

TIA, Thall.

Comment: share the plugin name and the plugin folders file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable automatic WordPress plugin updates:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
```

Put above code in functions.php

Disable automatic WordPress theme updates:

```
 add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Disable automatic updates in WordPress by adding this line of code in your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with you.

I've came through a post which helps you to stop asking about you for the plugin update. For example I've **wp-csv** plugin, code in functions file will be like:

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['wp-csv/wp-csv.php'] );
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Ref link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/turn-off-auto-update-for-single-plugin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks @Vivek, it does go some way to fixing the issue, however I'm looking to do this as a blanket for all plugins, without having to locate and add the location of all plugins declaration files